# How can I set a user's display name and email with Firebase signInWithCredentials()

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am writing a login / signup page for my `React Native` app, and I am using Firebase's `signInWithCredential()` function.

As you can see in the code below, I pass a credential and if the response shows it's a new user, I append to my database, otherwise I sent them to the home screen.

```
await firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithCredential(credential)
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
            setShowVerifier(false);
            setShowRegistration(true);

            // append data to database if user is new
            const data = { firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber };
            db.collection("users")
                .doc(response.user.uid)
                .set(data)
                .then(() => {
                    setShowPhoneNumber(true);
                    setShowVerifier(false);
                    setShowRegistration(false);

                    navigation.navigate("Home");
                }).catch(() => {
                    alert("Error creating account, try again");
                });
        } else {
           setShowVerifier(false);
           setShowPhoneNumber(true);

           // set verification code to empty string
           setVerificationCode("");

           navigation.navigate("Home");
        }
    });
```

When I find out that the user is in fact a new user, how would I go about updating that user's Firebase auth information, like their displayName and email? (shown below in JSON response)

```
"user": Object {
    "displayName": null,
    "email": null,
    "emailVerified": false,
    "isAnonymous": false,
    "lastLoginAt": "1603914278694",
    "photoURL": null,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this chunk of code to the code chunk found above.

```
auth.currentUser.updateProfile({
    displayName: firstName + " " + lastName,
    email: email,
});
```

Updated code chunk:

```
await firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithCredential(credential)
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
            setShowVerifier(false);
            setShowRegistration(true);

            // append data to database if user is new
            const data = { firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber };
            db.collection("users")
                .doc(response.user.uid)
                .set(data)
                .then(() => {
                    setShowPhoneNumber(true);
                    setShowVerifier(false);
                    setShowRegistration(false);

                    navigation.navigate("Home");
                }).catch(() => {
                    alert("Error creating account, try again");
                });
        } else {
           setShowVerifier(false);
           setShowPhoneNumber(true);

           // set verification code to empty string
           setVerificationCode("");

           navigation.navigate("Home");
        }
    });
```